# Programmatically access Google API Authorization in a Background Java Process

Tags: java, api, gmail, authorization

The Code is running on a JavaEE Server (Wildfly) and runs on a Linux OS (Raspbian without GUI). I want to access Gmail API in a Background Process but he always asks me "Please open the following address in your browser: ....". Can I somehow prevent that?

```
InputStream in = XmlServiceImpl.class
        .getResourceAsStream("/mail.connector/client_secret.json");
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.load(
        JSON_FACTORY, new InputStreamReader(in));

// Build flow and trigger user authorization request.
GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow flow = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Builder(
        HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, clientSecrets, SCOPES)
        .setDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_FACTORY)
        .setAccessType("offline").setApprovalPrompt("force").build();
Credential credential = new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow,
        new LocalServerReceiver()).authorize("user");

try {
    HTTP_TRANSPORT = GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport();
    DATA_STORE_FACTORY = new FileDataStoreFactory(DATA_STORE_DIR);
} catch (Throwable t) {
    t.printStackTrace();
    System.exit(1);
}

Credential credential = new Gmail.Builder(HTTP_TRANSPORT, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
        .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME).build();

Gmail service = null;
try {
    service = getGmailService();
} catch (IOException e1) {
    // TODO Exception Handling
    e1.printStackTrace();
}

ListMessagesResponse response = null;
try {
    response = service.users().messages().list(USER_ID)
            .setIncludeSpamTrash(true).execute();
} catch (IOException e) {
    // TODO Exception Handling
    e.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: Authorization has to be done at least once through browser. For later logins, you can store the token/credential and access them whenever required. Your case is quite novel, but I think it will be better if you use a service account.

Comment: But can I access Gmail Mails via Service Account? I got no "Google for Works" Account.

Comment: I doubt if you could access Gmail with a service account. You can use Google Drive since you can share folders and documents with the service account.

Comment: I used the JavaMailAPI to read mails from my GMail Account. See [Link](https://java.net/projects/javamail/pages/Home) Works perfect.